# System involving rank-deficient matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{W}$ be two known real matrices with size $k \times n$, with $n < k$, satisfying that

$\bullet \quad\text{rank}(\mathbf{W}) = r < n$,

$\bullet \quad\text{rank}(\mathbf{V}) = n$.

I am facing the following system of matrices, where $\mathbf{C}$ is an unknown matrix of size $k\times n$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\mathbf{W}^\top \mathbf{C} \mathbf{C}^\top = \mathbf{C}^\top \\
\mathbf{W}^\top \mathbf{C} \mathbf{V}^\top = \mathbf{V}^\top
\end{cases}
$$
This leads to $\mathbf{W}^\top \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{I}$ but, as $\mathbf{W}$ is rank-deficient, I was not able to find a solution. Are there other solutions for $\mathbf{C}$ that I am missing? Has the previous equation a solution for $\mathbf{C}$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the case that your problem has no solution. First, rewrite the second equation of the system as follows:
$$
W^TCV^T = V^T \implies [W^TC - I]V^T = 0
$$
Note that $V^T$ is a matrix with full row-rank. It follows that
$$
[W^TC - I]V^T = 0 \implies W^TC - I = 0 \implies W^TC = I.
$$
Now, because $W$ is rank-deficient, $\operatorname{rank}(W^TC) \leq \operatorname{rank}(W) < n = \operatorname{rank}(I)$, which means that we cannot have $W^TC = I$.